# Change the start number of Primary Key in existing access database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2010

I've an access 2010 database with a relationships and constraints between tables.

I would like to change the start position of existing primary key to start from specific number and then change the order of other rows like normal auto-increment.

Changing the primary key should change also the related tables references as there's cascade on update.

Can I do that using Macro or VBA? How can I change the primary key number without deleting the column or the relationship, and the changing must be applied on other related tables?